# How to carry dhcpd settings over during VMware Workstation upgrade?

Tags: networking, vmware, dhcp, vmware-workstation

The network setup for VMware Workstation appears to get lost time and time again during version upgrades. Since I had it again this morning, I thought I'd finally tap into the wisdom of the hive mind and see if anyone has a solution.

My setup is a Windows 10 with VMware Workstation Pro 15.x which I just upgraded today to 15.5.0.

The default dhcpd configuration file is located at `C:\ProgramData\VMware\vmnetdhcp.conf` and looks something like this:

```
#
# Configuration file for VMware port of ISC 2.0 release running on
# Windows.
#
# This file is generated by the VMware installation procedure; it
# is edited each time you add or delete a VMware host-only network
# adapter.
#
# We set domain-name-servers to make some clients happy
# (dhclient as configued in SuSE, TurboLinux, etc.).
# We also supply a domain name to make pump (Red Hat 6.x) happy.
#
allow unknown-clients;
default-lease-time 1800;                # default is 30 minutes
max-lease-time 7200;                    # default is 2 hours

# Virtual ethernet segment 1
# Added at ...
subnet 192.168.41.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.41.128 192.168.41.254;            # default allows up to 125 VM's
option broadcast-address 192.168.41.255;
option domain-name-servers 192.168.41.1;
option domain-name "localdomain";
default-lease-time 1800;
max-lease-time 7200;
}
host VMnet1 {
    hardware ethernet 00:50:56:C0:00:01;
    fixed-address 192.168.41.1;
    option domain-name-servers 0.0.0.0;
    option domain-name "";
}
# End

# Virtual ethernet segment 8
# Added at ...
subnet 192.168.65.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.65.128 192.168.65.254;            # default allows up to 125 VM's
option broadcast-address 192.168.65.255;
option domain-name-servers 192.168.65.2;
option domain-name "localdomain";
option netbios-name-servers 192.168.65.2;
option routers 192.168.65.2;
default-lease-time 900;
max-lease-time 3600;
}
host VMnet8 {
    hardware ethernet 00:50:56:C0:00:08;
    fixed-address 192.168.65.1;
    option domain-name-servers 0.0.0.0;
    option domain-name "";
    option routers 0.0.0.0;
}
# End
```

Well, I was lying, there is a line at the bottom (past the `# End`) which looks something like:

```
include "my-dhcp-hosts.conf";
```

This file contains `host` blocks for the hosts that I want to assign fixed IPv4 addresses and host names.

And while the upgrade process carried over the settings for `VMNet1` and  `VMNet8` (subnet range etc) it simply removed my `include` line *after* the `# End`.

While I separated the host configuration nicely using this method, it gets lost time and time again during version upgrades, although [the wording of the documentation](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/15.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-04D783E1-3AB9-4D98-9891-2C58215905CC.html) suggests there *are rules* to how the `vmnetdhcp.conf` is being "auto-updated" (for lack of a better phrase):

> Changes made **to the read-only section of the DHCP configuration file** are lost the next time you run the virtual network editor.

Now this may not seem like a big nuisance, but it does become one when you do it time and time again and on more than a single machine. Besides, after changing it, one also has to restart the `VMnetDHCP` service.

What is the way to have VMware Workstation retain *my changes* outside of the clearly marked sections ...

```
# Virtual ...
# Added ...
...
# End
```

... during version upgrades?

Comment: You could write a simple script that backups the configuration file, which could be ran, before the setup for the VMWare Workstation.

Comment: @Ramhound that kinda works, but it's a crutch. It's roughly what I currently use as a workaround. But I am holding out for a fix rather than a wonky workaround.